# When can we write $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

When can we write $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$?
Intuitively, this is quite sensible as we are partitioning the interval $(0,\infty)$ as an increasing interval of $n$. But does this result hold true everytime?

Also, it is known that $\int_{0}^{n} f(x) dx$ exists for all $n$.

Comment: I thought the definition of what $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ meant was $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} f(x) dx$. If so, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{n} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ is always true. However, perhaps someone else here knows of, and can describe, situations where there's some difference between the $2$ expressions.

Comment: @BorKari:There is only one side to approach $+\infty$ from.

Comment: From Classical Lebesgue Integration Theory: if $f$ is dominated by some integrable $g$, then the equation holds

Answer (score 5):

If n is only an integer and we're imagining a sequence, then I have a counterexample to that proposition. Let $f(x) = \cos(\pi x)$. Then,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n \cos(\pi x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}0=0$$
But the quantity $\int_0^\infty \cos(\pi x) dx$ does not exist.